# is the 21+3 blackjack side wager patent still active for Galaxy gaming

Tags: expired

Is the 21+3 blackjack side bet patent expired. It is a variation of three card poker using the players first two cards and the dealers up card

Comment: What patent is that? If you have a patent number please provide it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a surprising number of patents related to [poker side bets](https://patents.google.com/?q=poker&q=side&q=bet&oq=poker%20side%20bet). Based on my Googling, I'm guessing the patent you are referring to is [US6012719A](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6012719A/en). It has a priority date of 7-22-1994 and was issued on 1-11-2000. Patents filed before June 8, 1995 expire either 20 years from their priority date or 17 years from their issue date which ever is later. As you can see from the Google Patent's page is listed as "Expired - Lifetime". Assuming this patent is the one you are asking about, it has expired.